# Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"] - using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

When trying to make a connection to the API, I get the below error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]
```

Note that I have verified the API key (JWT) does not have any carriage returns, new lines, or tabs. Testing the API key and endpoints in Postman is successful.

Code (and test verifying key is free of carriage returns, new lines, and tabs):

```
console.log(/\t\r\n/.test(api_config.API_KEY)); // test to determine if key has carriage returns, new lines, or tabs


const connectionConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_config.API_KEY
    }
}

axios.get(api_config.BASE_URL + api_config.CAMPUSES_OPTIONS_URI, connectionConfig)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Postman Code snippet]

Have you tested the API with Postman?

If that's work, you can easily create the code snippet based on your API with headers, body, etc.

Comment: Postman works so I copied the exact header into my code and that also worked. Then I pasted the header into my api_config file and used my variable instead and that's when I get the error. I think it's because I'm accessing the key from an external file. If I do a console.log, the key looks fine. I can't commit the API KEY which is why I'm using a file being ignored by git. Thoughts?

Comment: UPDATE: I copied the API key directly from the Postman code and used this as my API Key and that appeared to be the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add more description in header

```
const connectionConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_config.API_KEY,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
}
```